# why is data expressed like this picture?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

i just read a xlsx file with using read.xlsx(openxlsx).

but I got the result of having a different value like this picture.

this column contains both numeric and character data in xlsx.

why is it happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Floating point error I believe - see this highly cited question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: thanks. Then, how can I move the original value?

Comment: `?round` the column to your desired number of significant decimals I reckon.

Comment: can i move them without any additional calculation in R?

Comment: Do the rounding in R after the import I mean.